# How do I cut text from beginning of a line and paste it at the end of the same line after adding :

Tags: notepad++

I have over 1000 lines of text in this format.

detekled@seznam.cz:smtp.seznam.cz:587:detekled@seznam.cz:pompo007:

I need to cut the email address at the start and paste it at the end like so.

smtp.seznam.cz:587:detekled@seznam.cz:pompo007:detekled@seznam.cz

Answer (score 0):

`:` is a separator
Use Replace with regex

```
find what: ([^:]+):(.*)
replace with: \2\1
```

Comment: Thanks mate, let me try it out and see..

Comment: when I run it this was the result..

detekled@seznam.cz:smtp.seznam.cz:587:detekled@seznam.cz:pompo007:smtp.seznam.cz:587:jknechtl@seznam.cz:Janinka007:

I was hoping for this:

smtp.seznam.cz:587:detekled@seznam.cz:pompo007:jknechtl@seznam.cz

Comment: @BENDYMAN Strange I get `smtp.seznam.cz:587:detekled@seznam.cz:pompo007:detekled@seznam.cz`